# 1-dimension matrix right division in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix

I've a matrix `A=[2,5,8]` and a matrix `B=[65,40,20]`.

In Python I want to take the result of right division `A/B=0.0787` *(I've tested it in Matlab)*

In Python I can't do `A/B` because in Python we can't take the inverse of a 1-dimension matrix. Like `inv(b)`, for example.

How can I do `A/B` in Python?

Comment: Your example A and B aren't matrices. What code in Matlab worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under the assumption that you consider A and B to be row matrices.

In that case, as you've mentioned, the inverse of B does not exist.  In general, the inverse of a matrix only exists for a subset of square matrices.  Since B is not a square matrix the inverse of B does not exist. And, since the division of 2 matrices A / B is equal to A * B<sup>-1</sup>, in your case the division of A and B does not exist.

That being said, you can generate a pseudo-inverse of B, [numpy link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html), which will allow you to divide A and B (kind of).  My guess is that Matlab is using the pseudo-inverse of B to do your computation.

To do the same thing in python try this:

```
A = numpy.array([[2,5,8]])
B = numpy.array([[65,40,20]])
A * numpy.linalg.pinv(B)
```

If you try this code, you'll discover another issue. Since A / B = A * B<sup>-1</sup>, the result of your calculation will be a matrix, not a scalar as you got from Matlab...

Comment: Thanks, but i want the result to be just a number, not a matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not sane from a mathematical standpoint. No idea what you did in Matlab, but it does not make sense mathematically.

Comment: Not a question of sanity.  The question is what matrix operation do you want to perform.  The operation of matrix division will return a matrix.  If you want just a number then you are looking for a different operation.  If you can tell me what exactly you want to happen then I might be able to help point you to the correct operation.